# Alternative or Suggestions for DoCmd.ApplyFilter?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that is bound to the main table in my access database. There are 5 comboboxes which shows the description of the IDs that are stored in the main database.

TruckModelID is stored in the tblTruckList and relates to the TruckModelID in tblTruckModel. TruckModelName is stored in tblTruckModel. 
I can make a simple search function where I can enter the ID but the user will not know the ID for specific models. How do I make some kind of search that can look at the value in txtFindTruck (my search field) and compare it to the name and then pick the correct ID and return the records from TruckList with the correct ID?

This is what I have been using when looking at values in tblMain:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[TruckID] Like ""*"" & Forms![Ändra Truck]!txtFindTruck & ""*"""
```

This is basically what I want:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[cmbTruckModelName] Like ""*"" & Forms![Ändra Truck]!txtFindTruck & ""*"""
```

However the actual value that the form uses is the TruckModelID not the TruckModelName

I am sure I have missed something in the description that makes it hard to understand, please do not hesitate to ask me anything :D also any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL `IN` clause to filter by a different query, like this:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[TruckID] IN(" & _
"SELECT TruckID From MyTable WHERE TruckModelName LIKE ""*"" & Forms![Ändra Truck]!txtFindTruck & ""*"")"
```

Fill in the blanks like your table name and it should work.

However, this might not be the best solution to your problem. If you are using a combo box, you can use a hidden ID column to do the searching, and include the actual model names in the combo box, which might be more user friendly.

See [How to hide columns in a ComboBox dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138402/how-to-hide-columns-in-a-combobox-dropdown) on how to hide columns.

Comment: Thank you Erik! You are a massive help! Thanks so much!